# How to check if the same downloaded file is being uploaded?

Tags: java, excel

We have an application and one of its features allows user to download an Excel file template from the Web portal. The user is supposed to make few changes in it and upload the same. As per the requirement we need to make sure that the user uploads the same file that he had originally downloaded.

So a different file with the same name and extension should not be allowed as well. Checking the checksum value won't help as it changes when the content is modified. Therefore we need some mechanism that would allow us to identify each file uniquely.

Comment: Assuming the file is generated for each download, include some identification number, e.g. in cell A1, and then making row 1 hidden.

Comment: If the user has to make "a few changes" then the file he uploads is _by definition_ different from the one he downloaded. So what is your measure of "sameness", as it applies to files? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @KevinBoone Let's consider each file downloaded has a unique id. User fills data in few empty fields and tries to upload it. At back end we have to check if the file being uploaded has the same id as the one downloaded. Strange as it may seem, that's the requirement. Thanks. :)

Comment: @cello Thanks! That seems plausible. :)

Comment: The suggestion of @cello might work well enough to "spoof" a solution -- to fool somebody who doesn't really understand the issues involved. The only "real" solution would involve providing users with a custom tool to edit the file, which only worked on the on-line representation, not on a local copy. In fact, you could make the whole thing web-based, like Google Sheets. Or just use Google Sheets :) Modern operating systems do not have a concept of "file identity" that is distinct from "file contents."

Comment: @KevinBoone Thanks Kevin. That makes more sense. I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file is generated for each download, include some identification number, e.g. in cell A1, and then making row 1 hidden.

In such a case, try to make the Excel document protected with a password, so that the user can only input data in certain fields to make sure the row is not unhidden and modified.

I've have, several years ago, implemented something similar, where I had a sheet full of data collected from other sheets, so I could easily import/export the data and then protect it and send it away.

Answer (score 0):

Something doesn't look "right" in the flow you've described. What are you trying to protect the server from? Malicious Excel? Wrong data supplied? In general, you should never trust a client, even if you embed some "information" into the file (not necessarily Excel) you cannot guarantee on server that the user won't extract it and paste to malicious file.

So in my understanding, you should better protect the data, not the Excel page itself. When the data gets submitted to the server after modifications if its important to your flow - extract it from excel and validate before storing.
If you work in "garbage in - garbage out" model - just store the Excel as is and don't deal with it.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. We have such validation in place but the requirement, strange it may sound, asks for unique identification of files. Thanks a lot for your suggestions.